# Why this regular expression will not compile?

Tags: c++, regex

I would like to use regular expression from here:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-B

I am trying to compile it like this:

```
#include <regex.h>
...
regex_t regexp;
if((regcomp(&regexp, "^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?", REG_EXTENDED)) != 0){
    return SOME_ERROR:
}
```

But I am stuck with return value of regcomp:

```
REG_BADRPT
```

According to [man](http://linux.die.net/man/3/regcomp) it means:

Invalid use of repetition operators such as using `*` as the first character.

Similar meaning at this [man](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/regcomp.3.asp):

`?`, `*` or `+` is not preceded by valid regular expression

I wrote parser using my own regular expression, but I would like to test this one too, since its officially in rfc. I do no intend to use it for validation though.

Comment: You have not taken account of the [escaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#Escape_sequences) required in C++ string literals...  Try printing your regex string and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Oli Charlesworth suggested, you need to escape  backslash `\\` for the question marks `\?`. See C++ [escape sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) for more information.

**test program**

```
#include <regex.h>
#include <iostream>

void test_regcomp(char *rx){
 regex_t regexp;
 if((regcomp(&regexp, rx, REG_EXTENDED)) != 0){
    std::cout << "ERROR :" << rx <<"\n";
 }
 else{
   std::cout <<  "   OK :"<< rx <<"\n";
 }
}

int main()
{

  char *rx1 = "^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?" ;
  char *rx2 = "^(([^:/\?#]+):)\?(//([^/\?#]*))\?([^\?#]*)(\\\?([^#]*))\?(#(.*))\?" ;

   test_regcomp(rx1);
   test_regcomp(rx2);

   return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
ERROR :^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
   OK :^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
```

---

The `\?`in your regex is the source of the REG_BADRPT error. It gets converted to `?`. If you replace it by `\\?`, regcomp will be able to compile your regex.

```
"^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?"

   OK :^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
```