# limited minimum and maximum length to email with regex but error

Tags: c, regex, posix

Is there any mistake with the following regex:

`^(?=.{1,32}$)\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-+.]\w+)*.\w+([-+.]\w+)*$`

I use this regex pattern to check email format and length, but execute with the error message below:

> Invalid use of repetition operators such as using '*' as the first character.

I try to use `\` in the front of my regex to escape `?`, the `regcomp()` can compile success but the result is wrong.

Here is my check strings:

> **test.test@test.com** --> failed, wrong result
>
> **test:test@test.com** --> failed, right result

### Environment

> Operating System :
>
> Linux debian8 3.16.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian
> 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u5 (2015-10-09) i686 GNU/Linux
>
> GCC
>
> Using built-in specs. COLLECT_GCC=gcc
> COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i586-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper
> Target: i586-linux-gnu Configured with: ../src/configure -v
> --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.9.2-10' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.9 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.9 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-i386/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-i386 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-i386 --with-arch-directory=i386 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --enable-multiarch --with-arch-32=i586 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i586-linux-gnu --host=i586-linux-gnu --target=i586-linux-gnu Thread model: posix gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)

Comment: Your Regex looks perfectly fine to me. You can use online tool to check such as https://regex101.com/ too. Maybe your error lies somewhere in the code or in the code-specific string syntax. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180762/why-this-regular-expression-will-not-compile for example.

Comment: it is likely that you regexp engine does not support positive lookahead - constructions like (?=a). To verify this assumption - try to compile construction "(?=a)a" . If it does compiled - try to match string "a" with it. It should match. If all this work - then it might be due to variable length of regex in positive lookahed - try to complie (?=a+).

Comment: @Dmitry Your assumption is  right. I think the regexp engine is not support.
Is there any way to dynamic minimum and maximum length to email address without positive lookahead?

Comment: "*Is there any way to dynamic minimum and maximum length to email address without positive lookahead?*" Just check the length of the string outside regex

Comment: @CodeDifferent you means use `strlen()` to check length and if length is correct than using regex to check the content?
Can i mix the length check and regex to single one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your tags and the hint that you are using `regcomp`, I'm assuming that you are using the standard Posix library `regcomp` and `regexec` functions to do the regular expression matching.

The regular expression syntax used by `regcomp` is fully documented in [`man 7 regex`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html) (or in [Posix itself](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09), which I find slightly more readable). There are many regex libraries in other languages which implement a larger variety of regex syntaxes, but you're not using those other languages. So if the syntax you're using is not in those documents, it won't work. That includes:

- Forward lookahead assertions like `(?=.{1,32}$)`. In fact, there are no lookaround assertions, nor any other syntax starting `(?`.
- The use of `\w` to mean alphanumeric characters. If you use Extended Regular Expressions (by providing `REG_EXTENDED` as the third argument to `regcomp` -- which you should *always* do), then the only thing that `\` does is prevent the following regular expression operator character from having special meaning. However, the Gnu implementation does offer some extension. It handles back-references, even though Posix only defines them in basic regular expressions. Some versions do handle `\w` and friends, but that might not work on other Posix regex implementations, such as Mac OS X.

You can use Posix character classes to get the effect of `\w`, `\W`, `\s`, etc. For example, word characters (`\w`) can be written as the character class `[_[:alnum:]]`, while non-space characters (`\S`) can be written as `[^[:space:]]`. Using this syntax is fully portable.

There is no workaround for lookahead assertions, except for creating a separate regular expression and matching it as well, starting at the correct point. But if you just want to check the length of the string, you don't need anything complex. Just check the length of the string:

```
size_t len = strnlen(str, maxlen + 1);
if (len >= minlen && len <= maxlen &&
    regexec(&preg, str, 0, 0, 0)) {
  /* The string matched, and its length is between minlen and maxlen */
} else {
  /* Not a match, or too short or too long */
}
```

(I used `strnlen`, which is in Posix 2008; it's implemented in glibc. The advantage is that if you only need to know that the string is not too long, `strnlen` avoids looking at too many characters. That is, if I'm going to reject a string with more than 32 characters, and the string I'm looking at is a megabyte, it would be silly to compute `strlen(str)`, which needs to look at every character in the string. `strnlen(str, 33)` will only look at the first 33 characters, and if the result is 33 I know the string was too long.)

If I understand what you're trying to check correctly, you could use the following slightly simpler regular expression:

```
[_[:alnum:]]([-+.]?[_[:alnum:]])*@[_[:alnum:]]([-+.]?[_[:alnum:]])*
```

which insists that `-`, `+` and `.`, if present, must be preceded and followed by word characters (so they can't be at the beginning or end, and you can't have two of them in a row.)

Answer (score 0):

This is your regex:

```
^(?=.{1,32}$)\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-+.]\w+)*.\w+([-+.]\w+)*$
```

You're escaping it as:

```
^(\?=.{1,32}$)\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-+.]\w+)*.\w+([-+.]\w+)*$
```

But, you're [probably] putting it into a string:

```
"^(\?=.{1,32}$)\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-+.]\w+)*.\w+([-+.]\w+)*$"
```

So, you have to double escape the backslash:

```
"^(\\?=.{1,32}$)\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-+.]\w+)*.\w+([-+.]\w+)*$"
```

Likewise, with all the backslashes:

```
"^(\\?=.{1,32}$)\\w+([-+.]\\w+)*@\\w+([-+.]\\w+)*.\\w+([-+.]\\w+)*$"
```

But, you probably don't want to escape the `?`, so we have:

```
"^(?=.{1,32}$)\\w+([-+.]\\w+)*@\\w+([-+.]\\w+)*.\\w+([-+.]\\w+)*$"
```

This is necessary because within a string, the C string parser will probably muck with them.  After the stripping, you want `regcomp` [or equivalent] to get `\w` and not just `w`.

Not all regex packages/libraries support `(?=`, so if you need that, you want to be sure yours does.  IIRC, `pcre` does.

Comment: I don't believe OP wants to match a literal `?=` at the beginning of an email address, which is what `\?=` would mean. The intent is certainly a forward lookahead, but Posix regexes don't have those, not even with Gnu extensions.

Comment: @rici Yes, I [hastily] riffed off what OP had done.  I've updated the answer to reflect your comment and to suggest pcre for fwd lookahead